# Anyone knows what Framework used to build react native documentation or the react js documentation?

Tags: documentation, document-management, react.js

I was goind to start a documentation and I was in love with the documentation made by react js or the react native documentation which is really awesome. I wanna know what framework used to create the docs. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to be found in the post
[DevDocs — API Documentation Browser](https://github.com/freeCodeCamp/devdocs):

> DevDocs is made of two pieces: a Ruby scraper that generates the documentation and metadata, and a JavaScript app powered by a small Sinatra app.

The above document describes how to generate your own documentation using this
software, which involves cloning Devdocs, but this is not the simplest job.

There exist equivalent products on the internet, free and paid, which would be
easier to use.

Comment: oh thanks, I finally figured it out.